# Creating user customizable printing app for ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, printing

I have users that want to be able to put in their own title bar, display the legend, scale bar, north arrow, add text/imagery/etc. just like ArcMap, but with the web maps instead.

Is this possible with ArcGIS Online?